# How do bind a datagridview to a collection whose objects contain a list property?

Tags: .net, data-binding, datagridview

As usual, I feel as though I'm missing something obvious, but I can't figure this out and can't find anything online (though I've found a few posts which ALMOST describe what I'm after), though I'm sure what I'm trying to do is common.

Say I have a list of these:

```
 public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Nicknames { get; set; }
}
```

and simply want to bind to a datagridview and display each Person's Nicknames in a combobox column. How is this done? I can load them in manually, row by row, but cannot figure out how to assign them as the DGV's datasource.

I've tried stuff like this with no luck:

```
private void CreateColumns()
    {
        BindingList<Person> people = GetAllPeople();

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        col.HeaderText = "ID";
        col.DataPropertyName = "ID";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);

        col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        col.HeaderText = "Name";
        col.DataPropertyName = "Name";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn colCombo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        //colCombo.DataPropertyName = "Nicknames";
        colCombo.DataSource = (from p in people select p.Nicknames.ToString()).ToList();
        colCombo.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        colCombo.HeaderText = "Nicknames";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colCombo);


        dataGridView1.DataSource = people;          
    }
```

Thanks for any ideas on this. I have a feeling I'm going to want to smack myself on the forehead when this gets answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't smack yourself on the forehead, I'm afraid you're going to have to load them manually row by row.  I'd put code like this in the DataGridView's DataBindingComplete event handler:

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e) {
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
        var person = row.DataBoundItem as Person;
        if (person != null) { 
            var combo = row.Cells["NicknameDropdown"] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
            combo.DataSource = person.Nicknames;
        }
    }
}
```

This approach does simplify your construction code for the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.  It becomes (notice no explicit data binding):

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn colCombo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
colCombo.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
colCombo.HeaderText = "Nicknames";
colCombo.Name = "NicknameDropdown";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colCombo);
```

A side note:
When I originally had to do something similar I didn't like the fact that the DataGridViewComboBoxCell loaded with no selected item.  I discovered that how'd I normally set a selected Combobox item didn't work (SelectedIndex, SelectedItem, etc.)  so I ended up using the DataGridViewComboBoxCell [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value.aspx) property.  You might add (danger prone) code like this to DataBindingComplete:

```
combo.Value = combo.Items["Big Joe"];
```

Comment: Thanks, Jay, for getting back to me. This is basically the direction I was headed in, and your response gives me a bit more confidence. I appreciate it.